# Publish Apk On Play Store for tablet only Android

Tags: android

How can i publish my application on play store for tablets only and reject all mobile phones. Is it possible to publish for tablet only on production.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Declaring an App is Only for Tablets**

---

If you don't want your app to be used on handsets (perhaps your app truly makes sense only on a large screen) or you need time to optimize it for smaller screens, you can prevent small-screen devices from downloading your app by using the  manifest element.

For example, if you want your application to be available only to tablet devices, you can declare the element in your manifest like this:

```
<manifest ... >     
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"  
                    android:normalScreens="false"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true"
                    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />   

   ...     <application ... >       
   ...     </application> 
</manifest>
```

[As per Android developers site.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your manifest file .May solve the problem

```
   <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false" />
```

Comment: what about compatibility screen tag ?

Comment: There's a specific section in the Android Developer site on 'Handset only" and "tablet only".

Comment: can you provide me with the link please

Comment: I did on the OP, and I've added an answer now with an extract!